# Equal width for little roman i,ii,iii,viii,

Tags: lists

As you may see in the figure, while using list environment, the little roman number i, ii, iii, iv, v, ... are different in their own width, not aligned. I think it is not good. But I'm not sure if it is proper to unify the width of every roman number, i.e. `(ii)` has the same width with `(i)`. If it is accepted to do, how can I do this? Or is there another way to increase the beauty of the look?

[image]

Comment: The `enumitem` package is convenient to align all the labels to the left with `\begin{enumerate}[align=left]`. Stretching them to ( i ) ( ii) (iii) etc would be mega-horrible.

Comment: What about using parentheses of the same width with centered number?

Comment: What about using arabic numbers? Or letters, if you need up to 26 items?

Comment: @gernot I need average 4 to 5.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\scaleroman}[1]{\resizebox{1em}{\height}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\scaleroman{\roman*})]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

No, thanks. `;-)`

[image]

Alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\scaleroman}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{viii}]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\scaleroman{\roman*})]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

No, thanks. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: +1 Both ghastly! Even as an exercise, the first is a blasphemy against the typographic gods which might not lightly be forgiven.

Comment: Thanks for replying. By the way, is there a font that has the equi-width roman numbers? (not by scaling)

Comment: @Eric Not that I know of; but how do you think they could do without scaling? And what about 48=xlviii or 87=lxxxvii?

Answer (score 1):

If you care for the uniform width of the labels, then roman numerals are the worst choice possible. Why not use arabic numerals (have the same width), lowercase or uppercase letters (have almost the same width, could be spaced such that the parentheses are in the same position).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep0mm
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
(1) & (a) & (A) & (i) & (I) \\
(2) & (b) & (B) & (ii) & (II)\\
(3) & (c) & (C) & (iii) & (III)\\
(4) & (d) & (D) & (iv) & (IV) \\
(5) & (e) & (E) & (v) & (V)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```